# What are the risks fixing a security vulnerability using attr_accessible and attr_protected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a security vulnerability with a recommended fix of switching from using `attr_protected` calls to `attr_accessible`.

I'm trying to understand the level of risks in making this change?  Is this considered a significant change?

Answer (score 0):

The change to `attr_accessible` will be more secure (not less), because you are moving from

**everything accessible by default and these ones are protected**

to

**everything protected by default and these ones are accessible**

The main risk is that you will break all your existing forms... unless you explicitly set the attributes to being accessible, or explicitly set each protected-attribute on a class.

---

So for example, with attributes: `id, email, phone number, zip_code and first_name`
these two would result in the same behaviour for existing attributes

```
# only protect these two attributes, everything else is open season
# a new attribute will start out accessible by default
attr_protected :id, :email
```

and

```
# only these attributes are accessible - everything else is protected
# a new attribute will start out protected by default
attr_accessible :first_name, :zip_code, :phone_number
```

Comment: Okay so just to validate, being a rails newbie, if I have the following set, assuming out of the attributes id, email, phone number, zip_code and first_name.  To change this from :attr_accessible :id, :email would be :attr_protected :phone_number, :zip_code, :first_name  Yes?  No?  Maybe?

Comment: Are you changed to attr_protected? I thought it was the other way around?

Comment: It is!  Sorry I'm even confusing myself.  Right now, for example, I have code as attr_accessible :id, :email.

Comment: Ah - in which case you are going from a lower-risk system to a higher-risk system... but the above answer still works, just reverse everything :)